# Error message says 'class' is deprecated, source does not contain 'class'

Tags: idris

I've just installed Idris v.1.0 and run the sample code from the [Proof section](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Proof#Idris) of Rosetta Code, piece by piece. Everything works fine up to the following fragment, which produces the *The 'class' keyword is deprecated. Use 'interface' instead.* error.

```
-- 3.1, Prove that the addition of any two even numbers is even. 

evensPlus1 : {a : MyNat} -> {b : MyNat} -> (EvNat a) -> (EvNat b) -> (EvNat (a :+ b))
evensPlus1 ea eb = ?proof31
```

There's not a single piece of 'class' in the source. What could be behind this issue?

Comment: Removing the annotations has solved the initial problem. I still get an error message (Proof 3.1/congS is not accepted) but that seems to be a different matter; probably the Rosetta code was written for a previous Idris version. Thank you for the help, Anton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are just warnings. The `%elim`-annotations are described in [this](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/reference/tactics.html#induction) *deprecated* chapter of the manual. You can safely delete them and finish the proof, e.g. like this:

```
evensPlus1 : (EvNat a) -> (EvNat b) -> (EvNat (a :+ b))
evensPlus1 EvO eb = eb
evensPlus1 (EvSS y) eb = EvSS (evensPlus1 y eb)

congS : {a : MyNat} ->  {b : MyNat} -> (a = b) -> (S a = S b)
congS Refl = Refl
```

Comment: Everything is fine now, thank you. 'Refl' was written as 'refl' in the Rosetta code.